# azure blob etag unqouted

Tags: azure, http, http-headers, azure-blob-storage

Using `curl` against http://MY_ACCOUNT.blob.core.cloudapi.de/MY_CONTAINER/MY_PATH gives header :

> ETag: 0x8C564F739B6442A

I thought [Etags need to be quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719214/syntax-for-etag).

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I used `curl` to check this issue on my side and I could retrieved the following result:

[image]

Moreover, use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer), you could right click your blob and click the properties option and check the Etag property as follows:

[image]

Or you could also leverage fiddler to check the response header:

[image]

Additionally, you could just access your blob via the browser and press F12 to open the developer tools and check the response header.

Comment: thanks for all these methods. upvoting so at least i know working for others. (these don't show quoted for me.)